# Pareto distribution: is there a uniformly most powerful test (UMP) at some level $\beta$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution with density

$$f_{\varphi}(x) = \dfrac{3\varphi^3}{x^4} \ \ \ x \ge \varphi > 0$$

Is there a [uniformly most powerful test (UMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) at some level $\beta$ for testing $H_0 : \varphi \le \varphi_0 \ \ \ \text{vs} \ \ \ H_1 : \varphi > \varphi_0$?

This exact same question has been asked in previous years [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505860/356308) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2496761/356308), but no one has provided an answer, so I think it would be useful to finally have this answered.

Comment: Please do not cross-post across sites.

Comment: Or, if you do, at least please give links to other posts.

Comment: See @StubbornAtom's answer here: [UMP level $\alpha$ test with distribution $f(x\mid\lambda) = \lambda x^{-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3269119)

Comment: @Saad I have already seen that, but I would like an answer that clearly explains how it is done for *this* specific problem.

Comment: Does this really warrant a +500 bounty? Your cross-post was closed as a duplicate of the same question linked above. It's a routine textbook question which I am sure you could have answered yourself with minor modifications after going through several similar questions on this site. More importantly, you haven't shared any personal input on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**. The sample likelihood is $$f_n(\textbf x)=\frac{3^n \varphi^{3n}}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^4}\mathbb 1_{\min \textbf x >\varphi}$$

and hence the likelihood ratio is

$$\frac{f_n(\textbf x|\varphi_1)}{f_n(\textbf x|\varphi_0)}=\left(\frac{\varphi_1}{\varphi_0}\right)^{3n}\frac{\mathbb 1_{\min \textbf x > \varphi_1}}{\mathbb 1_{\min \textbf x > \varphi_0}}$$

This is monotonically non-decreasing in the test statistic $T(\textbf x)=\min \textbf x$ (e.g. it is $0$ for $\varphi_0<\min \textbf x<\varphi_1$ and then a positive constant for $\min \textbf x>\varphi_1$). This allows us to use the Karlin-Rubin theorem from the UMP Wikipedia page, which states that the test

$$\delta(T(\textbf x))=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } T(\textbf x)>c\\0&\text{if }T(\textbf x)<c\end{cases}$$

where $c$ is chosen such that $E_{\varphi_0}\delta (T(\textbf x))=\alpha$ is the UMP test of size $\alpha$ for testing

$$H_0:\varphi\le \varphi_0\\
H_1:\varphi>\varphi_0$$

It remains to compute $c$. Before doing this we need the cdf of $\text{Pareto}(x_0, \alpha)$ which has density $\frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}, x>x_0$. The cdf is $\int_{x_0}^x \frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{t^{\alpha+1}}dt=\alpha x_0^\alpha \frac{t^{-\alpha}}{-\alpha}\bigg |_{t=x_0}^x=-x_0^\alpha \left(x^{-\alpha}-x_0^{-\alpha}\right)=1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^\alpha$. We also need the distribution of the minimum of $n$ iid Pareto random variables. $\Pr(\min \textbf X>x)=\Pr(X_1>x)\dots \Pr(X_n>x)=\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^\alpha\dots \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^\alpha=\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^{n\alpha}\sim\text{Pareto}(x_0, n\alpha)$. So the minimum of $n$ iid $\text{Pareto}(\varphi_0, 3)$ random variables is $\text{Pareto}(\varphi_0, 3n)$. We have $$\begin{split}\alpha&=E_{\varphi_0}\delta (T(\textbf x))\\
&=P(T(\textbf x)>c|\varphi_0)\\
&=\left(\frac{\varphi_0}{c}\right)^{3n}\end{split}$$

Solving for $c$ finds that $c=\frac{\varphi_0}{\alpha^{\frac 1 {3n}}}$. Thus the UMP test is

$$\delta(\min \textbf x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if } \min \textbf x > \frac{\varphi_0}{\alpha^{\frac 1 {3n}}}\\
0&\text{ if } \min \textbf x < \frac{\varphi_0}{\alpha^{\frac 1 {3n}}}\end{cases}$$

That is we reject the null for sufficiently large minimum statistic. Hope this helps!