# How to most powerful test of size $\alpha$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have to find the uniformly most powerful size $\alpha$ test for the following pdf-
$$f(x|\theta) = exp\{-(x-\theta)\}$$ $x>\theta$

The pdf is 0 for $x\leq\theta$ ,
Null hypothesis is $\theta = \theta_0$ and alternate is $\theta =\theta_1$.
 I am given an i.i.d. sample from the above pdf. I was trying to apply the Neyman pearson lemma but the relative likelihood is constant so I don’t know how to find the UMP size $\alpha$ test, can someone please provide the solution.

Comment: If $\theta_1>\theta_0$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899114/mp-test-construction-for-shifted-exponential-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1 alongwith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem. If $\theta_1\ne \theta_0$, there is a bit more work.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot

Comment: So is it $\theta_1>\theta_0$? Actually you can ignore the wiki link in my last comment. Also please choose where you want to ask instead of cross-posting.

Comment: Yes it is $\theta_1>\theta_0$, and I will keep it in mind to not cross post in the future.